# FROM_DEVICE DMA Request hangs Linux on multi CPU server motherboard

Tags: linux-device-driver, fpga, dma, pci-e

I am developing FPGA based PCI Express (PCIe) device that should work under Linux OS, so I am writing the Linux kernel driver also. One of the features of the device is that it can write data to Linux Host RAM in DMA mode using the most simple mechanism:

1. Device driver allocates contigues region (128 KB) of memory and gets the dma (bus) address for that region
2. Driver writes the dma address to the FPGA PCIe device
3. FPGA PCIe device just genereates Memory Write PCIe Transactions with address starting on that dma address (Of course driver sets the Bus Master Bit)

Everything is working just fine on a simple desktop single CPU PC with Ubuntu OS. But when I try to  run the same code (both rtl and the driver/linux app) on Supermicro server with two physical Intel CPUs - the computer hangs right at the Memory Write transation generated by my device.

Here is some code from the driver

```c
// I am using 64 bit dma addressing
if (!dma_set_mask_and_coherent(&pdev->dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(64))) 
    printk(KERN_WARNING "%s: using 64bit DMA addressing\n", DRIVER_NAME);

...

// memory allocation and mapping
struct page *dma_pages;
dma_pages = alloc_pages_node(NUMA_NO_NODE, GFP_ATOMIC | __GFP_NOWARN | __GFP_COMP | __GFP_MEMALLOC, mem_order); 
    
virt_addr = (unsigned long)page_address(dma_pages);

# this dma address goes to fpga
dma_addr = dma_map_single(&fpga_dev->pdev->dev, virt_addr, size, DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);
```

What I have tried so far on the server:

1. Checked the pcie link, it's ok. CPU can read/write FPGA registers and transfer data to FPGA
2. Disabled IOMMU during linux kernel boot (iommu=off intel_iommu amd_iommu=off)
3. Disabled Intel VT-d in BIOS
4. Tried to experiment with NUMA (disabled, enabled, tried to allocate memory on different nodes - near device and not)
5. Checked different PCIe slot, different CPU. Now the FPGA card is connected to the slot where another PCIe card (NIC) was working correctly.

I searched a lot in google and even discussed the matter with ChatGPT - without success. Any ideas what to do next?

What can be the difference between desktop PC with one CPU (where everything is working fine) and two socket supermicro server with two Intel CPUs?

Comment: Linux kernel has a framework to support FPGAs (see _drivers/fpga_), why do you need a custom driver?

Comment: Is there any error checking for the return values of `alloc_pages_node()` (`!= NULL`) and `dma_map_single()` (`!= DMA_MAPPING_ERROR`)?